# Setting up ActiveMQ bridge to connect to different implementations of MOM

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, ibm-mq, tibco-ems

I would like to deploy ActiveMQ in order to connect and communicate with other MOM implementations of jms such as WebsphereMQ, Tibco EMS, Oracle WebLogic JMS etc.

As far as I have researched online this seems to be possible by building a so-called bridge on top of activemq that will be able to communicate with the other end, regardless of the underlying wire protocol each jms implementation uses.

Examples though are scarce and often times minimal and so a point of confusion is whether I need to include jms client jars from each such implementation (Weblogic, WebsphereMQ, TIBCO EMS etc) in my classpath and bridge configuration. Can this be done without any such jars?

Since the goal is to connect to separate organizations MOMs I would like to avoid using any 3rd party, potentially licensed, jar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ...a point of confusion is whether I need to include JMS client jars
>   from each such implementation (Weblogic, Websphere MQ, TIBCO EMS etc)
>   in my classpath and bridge configuration. Can this be done without any
>   such jars?

TL;DR: You need the vendor's proprietary classes.

JMS defines the API and leaves the wire format and other implementation details to the transport vendor.  Furthermore, in the proprietary implementations the wire formats can change significantly version to version. (One of the advantages of proprietary code is the ability to make such large structural changes when doing so improves performance, reliability or function.)

The one place where two JMS implementations have commonality is when the messages are in memory.  Since all of the transport vendor's implementations inherit from the same Java JMS classes, it is usually possible to instantiate message objects from two different transport vendors and copy from one to the other.  To do this, you *must* have the jars of each supported transport provider.

In fact, this is how most JMS bridge products that I've used work.  The bridge code uses fully-qualified class names to reference the classes from two different vendors.  It then creates two connection factories, one for each transport, and two different destinations, also one for each transport.  It then reads a message from a queue on one provider, copies it to the message object on the other transport provider, then writes the message.

There are of course many "gotchas" with this approach.  I'll list a few of the obvious ones:

- Mapping destinations across providers is manual.
- Identity propagation is not enforceable and requires the bridge to have quasi- or full-admin rights.
- Transactionality across the providers is at best difficult, at worst impossible.
- Correlation identifiers must be mapped by the bridge if they are mapped at all. This makes the bridge more complex and requires it to use a database or other persistent storage.
- The vendor-specific classes often have a superset of the attributes and methods specified by the JMS spec. If used, these are stripped away during the copy.
- Due to message segmentation, grouping and other affinities, there may not be a 1:1 correlation across the bridge.
- Due to differences in implementation of such things as high availability, the physical network structure of one transport provider may not map 1:1 to that of another transport provider.  This tends to limit the bridge function to the simplest common denominator of the two transports.
- The issues raised by a general-purpose bridge include all of the issues of a 2-party bridge, raised as the exponent of the number of transports supported.  So if a 2-transport bridge is of difficulty `x`, then for planning purposes assume a 5 transport bridge is of difficulty `(x)**5`.

That's not to say "don't code a bridge" since these turn out to be very useful.  Just be aware, it's not a trivial task.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that's not possible at least on the IBM MQ end.  JMS is just an API and each provider is free to implement it the way they see it fits (as you rightly said its not a wire protocol).  provider jars are essential to connect to a JMS product.

Answer (score 0):

**We have concept called Virtual destinations, try that**

Comment: This should be a comment to OP's question. Not an answer to question. Once you earn, 50 rep, you can post comments. . Beware that, all the posts are peer reviewed by other Stack Overlfow users.